# Can I safely delete folder $GetCurrent in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, disk-cleanup

I have Windows 10 Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.48). And just noticed that there is a folder in the root of C:\ drive:

```
C:\$GetCurrent
```

With subfolders:

```
Logs
media
SafeOS
```

The total size of folder is almost 4GB. Can I safely delete this folder to clean up HDD space?

Comment: If the upgrade completed then it should be fine since it's created during the upgrade process so if you go to upgrade in the future and it;s needed and not there then it will get created automatically during that process: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/95115-delete-getcurrent-folder-windows-10-a.html. If you're not in the middle of an upgrade or have one pending, then it is fine to delete.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> *Can I safely delete folder $GetCurrent in Windows 10?*

Yes.

> **What Is $GetCurrent?**
>
> The $GetCurrent directory is created during the upgrade process. It
>   contains log files about that last Windows upgrade process and may
>   also contain the installation files for that update. On our system,
>   the $GetCurrent folder took up 3.38 gigabytes after upgrading to the
>   Creators Update. This is because the folder contains leftover Windows
>   Update installation files.
>
> Assuming you don’t need to review the log files stored here and you’ve
>   finished installing the latest Windows Update, this folder is safe to
>   remove. In theory, Windows should automatically delete these files
>   itself after 30 days at most. In practice, we noticed that this folder
>   was still lying around more than a month after upgrading to the
>   Creators Update, so we had to delete it ourselves.

However, contrary to popular belief, the built-in Disk Cleanup utility won't delete it:

> The [Windows Disk Cleanup tool](https://www.howtogeek.com/266337/what-should-i-remove-in-disk-cleanup-on-windows/) doesn’t automatically delete these
>   folders. However, it does delete [the $WINDOWS.~BT and ~WINDOWS.~WS
>   folders](https://www.howtogeek.com/268667/what-is-the-windows.bt-folder-and-can-you-delete-it/) you may also see in your C: drive.
>
> To get rid of these folders, you can just delete them the old
>   fashioned way. Select the folders in File Explorer, right-click them,
>   and select “Delete”. File Explorer will prompt you to provide
>   administrator permission to delete them, and you can then empty your
>   Recycle Bin to free up the space they take on your device.
>
> Deleting these folders won’t cause any problems if you don’t need to
>   review the log files they contain and if you aren’t in the middle of
>   installing a new update to Windows. Even if Windows does need the
>   files to install an update, it will just download them again.

Source:  [What Are the $GetCurrent and $SysReset Folders, and Can You Delete Them?](https://www.howtogeek.com/308301/what-are-the-getcurrent-and-sysreset-folders-and-can-you-delete-them/)